# Sub domain tracking in adobe analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

I have a main website mywebsite.com where I have some links which takes to abc.mywebsite.com, both of these websites are being tracked using Adobe Analytics. When user moves from parent domain to subdomain same mid is being carry forwaded. 
User can navigate to subdomain only from the parent domain. If i look at my entry pages report, I see that for 50% of the traffic subdomain is the entry pags, how is this possible? somewhere mid is getting broken when moving from parent to sub domain?

Answer (score 1):

**First thing to check:**

Login to Adobe Analytics.

Go to Admin > Report Suite Manager.

Select your report suite from the list.

Go to Edit Settings > General > Internal URL Filters.

Make sure the subdomain matches a filter in the list. For example, if you have full `www.mywebsite.com` as a filter, also add `abc.mywebsite.com`, OR, change the filter to `mywebsite.com`

**Next thing to check:**

Is `www.mywebsite.com` secure (https)? Is `abc.mywebsite.com` ? If you go from a secure (https) page to a non-secure (http) page, `document.referrer` will not have a value, so Adobe Analytics will not record a referring URL. Without a referring URL, it will count it as an entry page.

If this is the case, you will need to update all your pages to be secure (https), or else do something to carry over the referring URL (e.g. have some javascript append the current URL to the target URL as a query param *(or a cookie, since it's the same root domain)*, and then on the target page, add some code to grab it and push to `s.referrer` if it exists).

**Next thing to check:**

Are some of your links pointing to a URL that triggers a server-side redirect? e.g. a vanity url that rewrites to a different URL? Is the server-side redirect directive configured to preserve / carry over the original referrer? If not, then on the target page, `document.referrer` will be blank. If this is the case, update your server configuration, or else do a solution like above.

Comment: If i break down entry pages by previous URL I'm getting the parent domain relates URLs which is correct. But question is,  why my subdomain showing as entry pages.